# How to find numeric values Before & After a String in an Excel Cell

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I hope I can get some assistance as to which formula to use. In the three rows below, I am trying to pull values from the right.

First line you can see that we have 10x50 meaning 10 packages have 50 items each. So I need to extract values Before and After X

It could be two cells, where I have values Before X and then next cell values After X. Sometimes the X is located a few spaces before the last word. I'm wondering if any kind soul can help please?

DEXTROSE 50% 2G/ML 10X50 LSSYR

LEVETIRACETAM INJ USP 500MG SSOL 25X5

DOBUTAMINE 100 INJ 1X5 ML AMP SAM (PF)

Comment: Doesn't look like you put much effort into solving this yourself. A simple look at the **Related** list (which is the same list of potential duplicates you were shown when posting) gives you at least two possible starts at doing so. Please look at those links (with the hint that there are at least two that by title alone are relevant) and see if you can at least try to do something yourself first. We're glad to help, but we're not a code/formula writing service.

Comment: I have never used Stackover flow and the last few hours I have been searching on youtube so I have been putting efforts in solving it and related searches is what I had been doing on youtube and google and just came across so much different information. I posted my question here and then started searching the site as well to save time. Thank you for the hint

Comment: When you created your account, it was suggested that you take the [tour] and read the [help] pages in order to familiarize yourself with the site. You may want to do that before your next post here. The proper use of the site is to search thoroughly *before posting*, not after, and the AI that shows potential duplicates is very, very good. You'll have a much better experience here if you keep that in mind. :-)

Comment: Be sure to also check out [mcve] as well as [ask] and [on-topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).  You can always [edit] your question at any time to add more information, plus possibly recover those [down-votes](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/121350/ive-just-been-downvoted-how-should-i-react)... :-)

Comment: Start with this: [https://www.ablebits.com/office-addins-blog/2015/10/07/excel-find-search-functions/]. The first thing you need to do is identify where the X is.

Answer (score 1):

This should work for you. Assumes the measurement is at the end, or near the end and looks for the last occurrence of "x". So if there is another x after this measurement, then it will not work. Also your example had only numbers between 1 and 99 (aka no more than two digits). So this formula will not work if the measurement is longer than 5 characters. aaXbb is OK. aaaXbb is not OK.

=TRIM(RIGHT(LEFT(A1,SEARCH("^^",SUBSTITUTE(A1,"x","^^",LEN(A1)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(A1,"x",""))))+2),5))